# Multitouch seems not to work on all 3 devices which I have tested

Tags: android, multi-touch

Can somebody tell me why I *ALWAYS* get "1" from :

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      int i = event.getPointerCount();
      System.out.println(i);
 }
```

I tested the app in Motorola Xoom - it show "1" when I put one finger but it does nothing when I put two fingers.

I have even added

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"          android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand" android:required="true" />
```

in Manifest.xml, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your onTouchEvent() function is not returning a value.  Eclipse won't even build the code without a return value, so I assume that you are returning something in your real application.

If you are not already doing this, try returning true, so that the system knows that you have handled the current TouchEvent successfully and can move on to the next one.

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      int i = event.getPointerCount();
      System.out.println(i);
      return true;
 }
```

**Edit:**

Try using an onTouchListener instead of onTouchEvent.  Something like this:

```
View yourView = findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_view);
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        int i = event.getPointerCount();
        System.out.println(i);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: the "return true;" is there, I just forget to put it here :D

Comment: Gotcha.  Well you don't need the <uses-feature> stuff to make multitouch work, it works just fine tracking at least 10 touches at a time on my Xoom:)  Could you show the larger onTouchListener?  What have you set it on?